# Is it best to prepare different sizes of pictures for faster loading

Tags: image

I just batch imported main image files onto Magento. 
Is it best to prepare thumbnail size, small size pictures for each item for faster loading?
I am not planning to use different images except for product detail pages, because they will be all the same.

But if it makes the difference in loading speed, I will resize the main pictures (800x800) to small size and upload them.They are mostly under 300KB.

Please advise.

Comment: Magento already does that automatically during its resize and caching, so this would be wheel reinvetion.

Comment: Auto-resizing even when I bulk import all the pictures, and they all reside media\import folder?

Comment: Magento copies them out of the import folder and stores them in its file system, then upon first call for use, it resizes and stores the resized image in the image cache. You will probably need to clear the import folder after each successful import.

Comment: Please add your comment as and anseer @FiascoLabs and please accept the answer Sword123 to mark this question as resolved. Thanks! :)

Comment: @AnnaVölkl - wanted originally to put a bit more information on original image storage location, program code that does the resize and store, and where the cache folder is located.

Answer (score 1):

Magento copies them out of the import folder and stores them at the imported file size in its file system which is found here:

> `media/catalog/product/*/*`
>
> `/*/*` represents the first two characters of the image file name so
>   there will be an `a` directory for all the images starting with `a`
>   and then another directory under that for the second character

Upon first call for use, Magento uses `gd2` to resize and store the resized image in the image cache.

> Storage is in subfolders under `media/catalog/product/cache` that use in the path,
>   a hash identifier, sizing info and a `/*/*` pattern similar to full size
>   storage

In the templates, the call to do this resize and store is usually something like:

> `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product,'image')->resize(265)`

You will probably need to clear the import folder after each successful import.